# confusion in Object.getOwnPropertyNames

Tags: javascript

Hi for the following code

```js
   function employee()
    {
     this.name="john";
    }

    employee.prototype={
      job:"manager",
      projects:["sales","training","construction"],
      display:function()
      {
       alert(this.name+" is a "+ this.job);
      }
    }

    var property=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(employee.prototype);
    alert(property);
```

I am getting result as job,projects,display but when i am defining properties using prototype in this way

```js
function employee()
    {
     this.name="john";
    }

    employee.prototype.job="manager";
    employee.prototype.projects=["sales","training","construction"];
    employee.prototype.display=function()
    {
     alert(this.name+"is a"+ this.job);
    }


 var property=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(employee.prototype);
 alert(property);
```

I am getting result as constructor,job,projects,display

My question is why i am not getting constructor in the result of first case?

Comment: Does my answer give you what you were asking for? If not,what is it missing?

Comment: I updated my answer with a correction to your first snippet.

Comment: @DanPrince this post relates to assigning an object literal to a prototype and how that overwrites the constructor object with the global `Object`. This question relates to very different code, different side effects, and of course - a different answer. I gotta disagree with you about the possible duplicate.

Comment: Oops. Seems I forgot my `console.log()` in place of your `alert()`. Switched that back for you, should be working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the `employee` function, it instantiates a Function instance, whose `prototype` contains a "constructor" property that points to the function. Assigning new properties to the prototype will preserve that. As a result, objects created with `new employee` will inherit this "constructor" property which will says what they've been constructed with.

```
function C(){}
console.log(C.prototype.constructor) // returns C
console.log(C.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor") // true

cosole.log(new C().constructor) // C
cosole.log(new C().hasOwnProperty("constructor") // false, it's inherited
```

However, when you overwrite the whole `prototype`, you're also removing the `constructor` property. Objects have a constructor of course (`Object`) but that is inherited, so it won't show up as "OwnProperties".

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an object to a prototype it changes the prototypal inheritance of that object. Since in the first example you assign an object directly to the prototype, the object ***itself*** is getting assigned to the prototype. That overwrites the `employee` constructor on the object prototype and replaces it with the global `Object` object. That's the key to what's going on.

You can verify that the constructor is overwritten by dropping this line of code into your first implementation:

```
console.log(employee.prototype.constructor === Object); // returns: true
```

As you can see, it returns `true` - verifying that the constructor of your `employee.prototype` isn't what you would expect (it would be set to itself... `employee`), but rather the global `Object` object.

Since the constructor is now set to the global `Object`, the `getOwnPropertyNames` method won't retrieve it among the `employee` object properties. The `getOwnProperyNames` method only retrieves methods belonging to that object itself - **not inherited objects**.

You can correct the first snippet by adding one line, as represented here in the code:

```
function employee() {
     this.name = "john";
   }

   employee.prototype = {
     constructor: employee, // <--- ADD THIS LINE
     job: "manager",
     projects: ["sales", "training", "construction"],
     display: function() {
       alert(this.name + " is a " + this.job);
     }
   };

   var property = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(employee.prototype);
   alert(property);
```

That resets the constructor of your object prototype, and now it will return `constructor` as well.

It's worth noting that restoring the constructor in this manner creates a property with `enumerable` set to `true`. Native constructors are not enumerable by default. So if you're using ES5, this might be the preferred way to restore the constructor:

```
Object.defineProperty(employee.prototype, 'constructor', {
enumerable: false,
value: employee
});
```

**Note:** this snippet must be placed after the `employee.prototype = {//code};`. Otherwise it will be overwritten again.

More reading on this: http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62402/javascript-constructor-and-namespace-in-object-literal-style/86222#86222